# How do I use filesystem functions in PHP, using UTF-8 strings?

Tags: php, utf-8, directory, filesystems, mkdir

I can't use `mkdir` to create folders with UTF-8 characters:

```
<?php
$dir_name = "Depósito";
mkdir($dir_name);
?>
```

when I browse this folder in Windows Explorer, the folder name looks like this:

```
DepÃ³sito
```

What should I do?

I'm using php5

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Just [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) the string desired as a filename.** *All* characters returned from `urlencode` are valid in filenames (NTFS/HFS/UNIX), then you can just `urldecode` the filenames back to UTF-8 (or whatever encoding they were in).

Caveats (all apply to the solutions below as well):

- After url-encoding, the filename must be less that 255 characters (probably bytes).
- UTF-8 has [multiple representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Precomposition_and_Decomposition) for many characters (using combining characters). If you don't normalize your UTF-8, you may have trouble searching with `glob` or reopening an individual file.
- You can't rely on `scandir` or similar functions for alpha-sorting. You must `urldecode` the filenames then use a sorting algorithm aware of UTF-8 (and collations).

#### Worse Solutions

The following are less attractive solutions, more complicated and with more caveats.

On Windows, the PHP filesystem wrapper expects and returns ISO-8859-1 strings for file/directory names. This gives you two choices:

1. Use UTF-8 freely in your filenames, but understand that non-ASCII characters will *appear incorrect* outside PHP. A non-ASCII UTF-8 char will be stored as multiple *single* ISO-8859-1 characters. E.g. `ó` will be appear as `Ã³` in Windows Explorer.
2. Limit your file/directory names to [characters representable in ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#ISO-8859-1). In practice, you'll pass your UTF-8 strings through [`utf8_decode`](http://php.net/utf8_decode) before using them in filesystem functions, and pass the entries [`scandir`](http://php.net/scandir) gives you through [`utf8_encode`](http://php.net/utf8_encode) to get the original filenames in UTF-8.

Caveats galore!

- If any *byte* passed to a filesystem function matches an [invalid Windows filesystem character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_file_name_limitations) in ISO-8859-1, you're out of luck.
- Windows *may* use an encoding other than ISO-8859-1 in non-English locales. I'd guess it will usually be one of ISO-8859-#, but this means you'll need to use `mb_convert_encoding` instead of `utf8_decode`.

This nightmare is why you should probably just [transliterate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556415/different-charset-on-different-server/1556989#1556989) to create filenames.

Comment: ISO-8859-1 is not more useful on Windows than ISO-8859-2 or ISO-8859-3. If you want to be safe, go with the 7-bit ASCII.

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me. `mkdir('Depósito')` creates `Dep%C3%B3sito` which I can't really believe is what the OP wants, even though he accepted this answer. See Umberto Salsi's answer for what is really going on and how to build a proper solution with `setlocale()` and `iconv()`.

Comment: PHP's behaviour has changed with PHP 7.1 - have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38466772/680382

Answer (score 12):

Under Unix and Linux (and possibly under OS X too), the current file system encoding is given by the `LC_CTYPE` locale parameter (see function `setlocale()`). For example, it may evaluate to something like `en_US.UTF-8` that means the encoding is UTF-8. Then file names and their paths can be created with `fopen()` or retrieved by `dir()` with this encoding.

Under Windows, PHP operates as a "non-Unicode aware program", then file names are converted back and forth from the UTF-16 used by the file system (Windows 2000 and later) to the selected "code page". The control panel "Regional and Language Options", tab panel "Formats" sets the code page retrieved by the `LC_CTYPE` option, while the "Administrative -> Language for non-Unicode Programs" sets the translation code page for file names. In western countries the `LC_CTYPE` parameter evaluates to something like `language_country.1252` where 1252 is the code page, also known as "Windows-1252 encoding" which is similar (but not exactly equal) to ISO-8859-1. In Japan the 932 code page is usually set instead, and so on for other countries. Under PHP you may create files whose name can be expressed with the current code page. Vice-versa, file names and paths retrieved from the file system are converted from UTF-16 to bytes using the ["best-fit" current code page](http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WindowsBestFit/).

This mapping is approximated, so some characters might be mangled in an unpredictable way. For example, `Caffé Brillì.txt` would be returned by `dir()` as the PHP string `Caff\xE9 Brill\xEC.txt` as expected if the current code page is 1252, while it would return the approximate `Caffe Brilli.txt` on a Japanese system because accented vowels are missing from the 932 code page and then replaced with their "best-fit" non-accented vowels. Characters that cannot be translated at all are retrieved as `?` (question mark). In general, under Windows there is no safe way to detect such artifacts.

More details are available in my reply to the [PHP bug no. 47096](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47096).

Answer (score 9):

PHP 7.1 supports UTF-8 filenames on Windows disregarding the OEM codepage.

Comment: If a file (saved under PHP 7.0) is named `DepÃ³sito` on the filesystem, how does PHP 7.1 see it? I would think PHP 7.0 and 7.1 would see two different filenames, with BC implications.

Comment: You're right. How 7.1 would see it, depends on the default_charset. Your example obviously witnesses the situation till 7.1 - UTF-8 string is passed to the ANSI API. To force the old behavior, it's only required to set the default_charset to some single byte codepage, usually to the system ANSI or OEM codepage. Otherwise, with default_charset=UTF-8 by default, file names are written and read correctly. More info here https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.1/UPGRADING#L391 . Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that Windows uses utf-16 for filesystem strings, whereas Linux and others use different character sets, but often utf-8. You provided a utf-8 string, but this is interpreted as another 8-bit character set encoding in Windows, maybe Latin-1, and then the non-ascii character, which is encoded with 2 bytes in utf-8, is handled as if it was 2 characters in Windows.

A normal solution is to keep your source code 100% in ascii, and to have strings somewhere else.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but can't you use mb_convert_encoding to convert the string the utf-16?

Answer (score 3):

Using the `com_dotnet` PHP extension, you can access Windows' `Scripting.FileSystemObject`, and then do everything you want with UTF-8 files/folders names.

I packaged this as a PHP stream wrapper, so it's very easy to use :

https://github.com/nicolas-grekas/Patchwork-UTF8/blob/lab-windows-fs/class/Patchwork/Utf8/WinFsStreamWrapper.php

First verify that the `com_dotnet` extension is enabled in your `php.ini`
then enable the wrapper with:

```
stream_wrapper_register('win', 'Patchwork\Utf8\WinFsStreamWrapper');
```

Finally, use the functions you're used to (mkdir, fopen, rename, etc.), but prefix your path with `win://`

For example:

```
<?php
$dir_name = "Depósito";
mkdir('win://' . $dir_name );
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use this extension to solve your issue: https://github.com/kenjiuno/php-wfio

```
$file = fopen("wfio://多国語.txt", "rb"); // in UTF-8
....
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try CodeIgniter Text helper from [this link](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/text_helper.html)
Read about convert_accented_characters() function, it can be costumised

Answer (score 0):

My set of tools to use filesystem with UTF-8 on windows **OR** linux via `PHP` and compatible with `.htaccess` check file exists:

```
function define_cur_os(){

    //$cur_os=strtolower(php_uname());

    $cur_os=strtolower(PHP_OS);

    if(substr($cur_os, 0, 3) === 'win'){

        $cur_os='windows';

    }

    define('CUR_OS',$cur_os);

}

function filesystem_encode($file_name=''){

    $file_name=urldecode($file_name);

    if(CUR_OS=='windows'){

        $file_name=iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $file_name);

    }     

    return $file_name;

}

function custom_mkdir($dir_path='', $chmod=0755){

    $dir_path=filesystem_encode($dir_path);

    if(!is_dir($dir_path)){

        if(!mkdir($dir_path, $chmod, true)){

            //handle mkdir error

        }
    }
    return $dir_path;
}

function custom_fopen($dir_path='', $file_name='', $mode='w'){

    if($dir_path!='' && $file_name!=''){

        $dir_path=custom_mkdir($dir_path);

        $file_name=filesystem_encode($file_name);

        return fopen($dir_path.$file_name, $mode);

    }

    return false;

}

function custom_file_exists($file_path=''){

    $file_path=filesystem_encode($file_path);

    return file_exists($file_path);

}

function custom_file_get_contents($file_path=''){

    $file_path=filesystem_encode($file_path);

    return file_get_contents($file_path);

}
```

**Additional resources**

- [special characters in "file_exists" problem (php)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685718/special-characters-in-file-exists-problem-php)
- [PHP file_exists with accent returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200750/php-file-exists-with-accent-returns-false)
- http://www.developpez.net/forums/d825883/php/php-sgbd/php-mysql/mkdir-accents/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname#Table_of_standard_uname_output

Comment: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string

Answer (score 0):

I don't need to write much, it works well:

```
<?php
$dir_name = mb_convert_encoding("Depósito", "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8");
mkdir($dir_name);
?>
```