# UTF8 not displaying proper after PHP processing

Tags: php, iis, encoding, utf-8, character

I have either a folder by the name of "同" (doesn't matter which character I use or how many)  after pulling it up with php shows the incorrect character or garbled text.

```
<?php
mb_internal_encoding('utf-8');
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        echo $file;
    }
}
closedir($handle);
}
echo "同";
?>
```

Returns:

```
Folder1index.php��同
```

It displays 2 'characters' as if it isn't encoded to UTF-8 properly. The browser is processing the page fine as UTF-8 due to the echo of the character in question.

Is this a php/code issue or is something else preventing it displaying properly?(IIS etc.)

Comment: Which encoding is your file-system using for file and directory names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the UTF-8 encoding of your scripts or the website, the problem most certainly is the encoding of the filenames in your file-system.

You first need to learn which encoding is used on the file-system level. If you get in the know you can re-encode the encoded file-names into UTF-8 (e.g. [`iconv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php); [`mb_convert_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)). They will display fine then on your website.

You write you're using IIS, so I assume you're running on windows. Please see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634832/file-exists-and-file-get-contents-fail-on-a-file-which-is-named-outputoio-t/6634924#6634924) and/or the related question [*What encoding are filenames in NTFS stored as?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050973/what-encoding-are-filenames-in-ntfs-stored-as) for more information.

Comment: Looked into the above iconv and mb_convert_encoding which was able to solve my issues. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an excellent thread on handling utf-8 file names in php - [How do I use filesystem functions in PHP, using UTF-8 strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525830/how-do-i-use-filesystem-functions-in-php-using-utf-8-strings)

In sort, you need to call urlencode/urldecode on file names. However its recommended that you use drupal's transliterate module - [Different charset on different server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556415/different-charset-on-different-server/1556989#1556989)