# download Zip file which is formed by multiple files in PHP

Tags: php, html, zip

I have some pdf files...I want to just download them as a collection and not one by one.
For that , I am trying to zip all pdf files and download. But I don't know why when in my code I am changing ZipArchive file name, it is saying damaged and corrupt.
My code is below:-

```
 function zipFilesAndDownload($file_names,$archive_file_name,$file_path)
{
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    //create the file and throw the error if unsuccessful
    if ($zip->open($archive_file_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE )!==TRUE) {
        exit("cannot open <$archive_file_name>\n");
    }
    //add each files of $file_name array to archive
    foreach($file_names as $files)
    {
        $zip->addFile($file_path.$files,$files);

    }
    $zip->close();
    //then send the headers to foce download the zip file
    header("Content-type: application/zip"); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$archive_file_name"); 
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
    header("Expires: 0"); 
    readfile("$archive_file_name"); 
    exit;
}



if($button=="Save as pdf")
{
$file_names = array();
foreach($a as $key=>$as)
{
 $file_names[] = $key.'.pdf';
}
}
$archive_file_name='zipped.zip';
$file_path='/resume/';
zipFilesAndDownload($file_names,$archive_file_name,$file_path);

?>
```

Can anybody help me out? Thanks in advance.

Its working fine but still i am facing 2 problems,1. I am getting error that Archive is corrupted if I change the name of archive_file_name to something other than given above. I don't why its happening    2.If I have got a zip file of say, 2 pdfs and then i again download a zip of only 1 pdf which was not same as earlier ones. But when I am downloading the zip of 1 pdf, then i am getting 3 pdfs......I don't know why ........please help me.

Comment: Which name have you tried? Which one is ok?

Comment: i have tried zipper1.zip and its not working. Its working with only zipper.zip name.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your `zipFilesAndDownload` function and it works well. So at first you should check your script, whether you have no characters or blank spaces sent before the `<?php` starting tag.

In the case that your script is running inside a CMS, you should also clear all output buffers: `while (@ob_end_clean());` (and if gzip headers was already sent, then also turn gz compression on again `ob_start('ob_gzhandler');`)

Also you can also check, if you have correctly set the $file_path and all your files exists, for example:

```php
$file_path='resume/';
if (!file_exists($file_path) || !is_dir($file_path)) {
    die("Invalid directory $file_path in ".getcwd());
}
// you can test the existence of your problematic files:
foreach ($file_names as $file) {
    if (!file_exists($file_path.$file)) {
        echo "$file not found.";
    } else {
        echo "$file is ok.";
    }
}
exit;
// end of test
zipFilesAndDownload($file_names,$archive_file_name,$file_path);
```

In Windows is also problem with UTF-16/UTF-8/international character encoding, see here: [PHP detecting filesystem encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522722/php-detecting-filesystem-encoding), [How do I use filesystem functions in PHP, using UTF-8 strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525830/how-do-i-use-filesystem-functions-in-php-using-utf-8-strings).

Comment: Its working fine but still i am facing 2 problems,1. I am getting error that Archive is corrupted if I change the name of archive_file_name to something other than given above. I don't why its happening    2.If I have got a zip file of say, 2 pdfs and then i again download a zip of only 1 pdf which was not same as earlier ones. But when I am downloading the zip of 1 pdf, then i am getting 3 pdfs......I don't know why ........please help me.

Comment: Hi, I also don't know why. But you can check the zipped file in some hexaviewer to see whether it begins correctly with PK letters or not. Other than that I dunno.