# Reading filename in multiple OS without encoding problem with Ruby

Tags: ruby, encoding, character-encoding, filenames

I want to get all filenames in UTF-8. For example, after I read filename in Windows, I do

```
filename = Iconv.iconv("UTF-8", "Windows-1251", filename)
```

In Ubuntu I don't convert filename and get it in UTF-8. Maybe exists some method to determine OS filename encoding?

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using? (1.8.x versus 1.9.x makes a big difference when talking about encoding and string handling)

Comment: Currently I use Ruby 1.8, but I can move on Ruby 1.9. So my question actually for both versions. But I don't work with Ruby 1.9.

Comment: Be careful, most OS support various encoding for their FS. For example, Windows does support UTF-16 ( cf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050973/what-encoding-are-filenames-in-ntfs-stored-as )

Answer (score 0):

I do this on Ruby 1.9 when I want to make sure things are in UTF-8:

```
if filename.encoding.to_s != 'UTF-8'
  filename.encode!('UTF-8')
end
```

Unless your OS gives a file name encoded with a coding system which doesn't support some special characters found on the file name, it can be encoded to UTF-8 without a hickup.