# php filenames with international names on windows

Tags: php, windows, internationalization, filenames

So, I have a little code, which uses locates files using an RecursiveDiectoryIterator and a RecursiveIteratorIterator to locate all the files in the directory. And I then check to see if the file exists, for some files it does not...

```
$fromIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir,FilesystemIterator::UNIX_PATHS | FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS));

foreach ($fromIterator as $file)
{
    if (!file_exists($file->getPathname()))
        print $file->getPathname() . "does not exist...\n";
}
```

I get some files like:
TÜBITAK_UEKAE_Kök_Sertifika_Hizmet_Saglayicisi_Sürüm_3.txt does not exist...

Is there something special I need to do to handle these filenames?

Comment: Some reading for you - http://evertpot.com/filesystem-encoding-and-php/. TL;DR - Windows is terrible. If this is for local development, I recommend a Vagrant LAMP box

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: How to create unicode filenames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467501/php-how-to-create-unicode-filenames)

Comment: I did see that thread, not creating a filename. Trying to use en existing filename PHP already found...

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with special characters, I suspect you are using UTF-8 encoding.

I don't think `file_exists()` will handle UTF-8 input properly. Try to use `file_exists(utf8_decode(...))` instead.

Comment: Good guess, but that had no impact.