# File names gets garbled after upload using php move_uploaded_file()

Tags: php, windows, file-upload, encoding, wamp

In my php code I want to upload files with Farsi names (e.g. نام.pdf) but the uploaded file name gets garbled after that. I am on a Win 7 (64bit) machine using WAMP as my development environment. I know that this problem is related to my working environment because the code works fine on a Linux production machine. How can I convert the `$uploaded['name']`to the supported encoding on the Windows machine? Please help me.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467501/php-how-to-create-unicode-filenames

Comment: @ryan-bemrose No it did not help me

Answer (score 1):

The problem is fixed on PHP 7.1, but if you intend to stick to the current version of the PHP you're using, there's a fix for Windows OS.

Please check the thread that I posted some time ago, and the solution I found (read the **FINAL EDIT** of my original post) :

[Solution to UTF-8 files names and PHP move_uploaded_file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48546476/using-iconv-to-keep-the-encoding)

Answer (score 0):

There is a PHP function called: `utf8_encode`. http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_xml_utf8_encode.asp

Also, you can make sure you have this line:
PHP Way:
`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

HTML Way:
`<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: i have used utf8_encode but the problem remains. The charset is also set to UTF-8 in the header.

Comment: Can you send a link of any farsi pdf file so I can test things for you? I also have RTL-language filenames and I never had this problem before.

Comment: I don't have a problem with the content of the files. The content don't change. My problem is only with the file name. You can rename a file to this (نام) and test the file.