# How to test for non ASCII characters in a file name

Tags: c#, asp.net

On a asp.net web site, a user tried to upload a file as an email attachment that contained an emdash in the file name. When sending this as an email attachment (exchange server) the file got converted to _utf8_B_************.dat

So, on a .aspx page, I need to be able to detect if an emdash is present in the filename of a file that is uploaded as part of the Request.Files collection.

```
string s = "a—b-";

byte[] arr = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
foreach (byte element in arr)
{
   Response.Write(element.ToString() + ",");
}
```

The string above has an emdash as the second character and a normal hyphen as the fourth character.

The code above prints 97,63,97,45 to the screen.

I assumed that as an emdash is not a valid ASCII character, either an error would be thrown or some indication shown that it was not a valid ASCII character. Yet it returns 63.

How can I detect an emdash in a file name so I can say to the user 'Your file name has an invalid character in it'? I have seen other questions on this issue, I can't get them to work.

Comment: From http://www.asciitable.com/ you can see that 63 is the value for a question mark.  When you call ASCII.GetBytes it forces the characters to ASCII, and uses a question mark when the character can't be converted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should probably do the trick:

```
    foreach (char c in s) {
        if (c >= 128) {
            Response.Write("Non-ascii char detected: {0}", c);
        }
    }
```

I believe that `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes` converts to ASCII first, so you should never see non-ASCII characters when you call that.

Comment: [_"ASCII characters are limited to the lowest 128 Unicode characters, from U+0000 to U+007F.
"_](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii.aspx). Your `if` condition will never be `true`.

Comment: Good catch. I updated the condition with 128. By the way, the original test ( > 256) did catch the em dash from the example given.

Comment: But it won't catch *&^%\: and other invalid (depending on the context) characters. Use framework-provided methods for work like this.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I detect an emdash in a file name so I can say to the user 'Your file name has an invalid character in it'?

That's the wrong way around, because tomorrow a user will upload a file with another unicode character your filesystem or its API doesn't support. Besides you don't need ASCII, because NTFS can handle [a lot more than 7 bytes per character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050973/what-encoding-are-filenames-in-ntfs-stored-as).

The right question is: "What characters can I use to save a file"? But then again you'll be tied to the filesystem implementation. You'd best just [generate a random filename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getrandomfilename.aspx) and write the file to that path, and store the filename in a database so you can view the original filename.

If you **do** want to save the file under the user-provided path, you'll have to remove [`Path.GetInvalidPathChars()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars.aspx) and [`Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars.aspx) from your the input.

If the problem is not the filesystem but the mail system, please show relevant code and error message.

Comment: The problem is not the file system. The file is saved on the server okay. But when the mail server sends that file, it converts it to a .dat. Change the file name so that the emdash is a normal hyphen, and the mail server sends it fine. There is no error code - it just converts the file to a .dat file and sends it.