# ElFinder and NTFS UTF-16 file names

Tags: encoding, utf-8, compatibility, utf, elfinder

I use WAMP server and ElFinder 2.x, it works fine except for filenames are encoded in UTF-8 when uploaded, so they look like `РЎРїРёСЃРѕРє РїСЂРµРґРїСЂРёСЏС‚РёР№ Р’Р Рљ123.xlsx` in Windows Explorer. It's OK, but it would be nice to be able to copy files with unicode filename to ElFinder's folder via Windows Explorer.

As far as I know NTFS uses UTF-16. nao-pon answered [here](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/issues/990) that one needs to set `encoding`, `locale` in connector options for multi-byte encodings. I've tried to set these options to 'UTF-16' and 'ru_RU.UTF-16', but ElFinder cannot load folder at all then and gives `Invalid backend configuration. Readable volumes not available` error.

UPD: it works fine with `'encoding' => 'CP1251'` but well... it doesn't list files with names like `한자.txt`.

Comment: There is Windows code page list. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd317756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @nao-pon i'm pretty sure the problem is http://stackoverflow.com/a/2051018/1119602