# Query related to i18n characters handling in C language

Tags: linux, windows, encoding, mount, nfs

I have an nfs share mounted on both Windows and Linux both, I created a folder named "`PRàjààjààjà`" from Windows file explorer. When I do "`ls /SomeFolder/MountedDir`" in linux I see that folder in below named format

"`'PR'$'\340''j'$'\340\340''j'$'\340\340''j'$'\340'`"

Now In Linux side I am using FTW callback function where I print the full path of folder and it doesn't print correctly.

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/ftw.html

```
int ftw(const char *path, int (*fn)(const char *,
       const struct stat *ptr, int flag), int ndirs);
```

I assume that the callback function gives me in utf8. I have limited understanding here.
Please help!

Expecting some answer to have same behaviour on Linux as well as Windows

Comment: Unix and posix has no notion of utf-8 or encoding. What you give you get back. Plain C *char*. Note they just restrict `\0`,`'\n`, and  `/` as fix value. So when you mount a disk, you may want to set what was the original encoding (on mount command/configuration), so that translation is done at filesystem layer.

Comment: hey thanks for your answer, I am using below command to mount
 mount -t nfs -o vers=3 XX.XX.XX.XX:/sharename /tmp/mountdir/

Can you please confirm what should be used here, I tried multiple options like
mount -t nfs -o vers=3,icharset=utf8 XX.XX.XX.XX:/sharename /tmp/mountdir/
mount -t nfs -o vers=3,utf8 XX.XX.XX.XX:/sharename /tmp/mountdir/

This didn't work for me

Comment: Unless something about Windows changed, I doubt you'd get utf-8 - I addressed a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59340830/10678955).