# PHP file-handling; Special characters in folder names

Tags: php, file

I am using rename() to move a file from one folder to another with php.

It works fine with folders which don't have the swedish å ä ö characters involved.

Is there any way around this? (except for changing the folder names to something without special chars)

The website is entirely in utf-8 format...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bit of a grey area looking at the the manual chapter on `rename()` and the User Contributed Notes. There is no word on what encoding should be used. Anyway, if the filesystem supports it, it should be possible to use UTF-8 in file names.

[**This SO question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525830/how-can-i-use-filesystem-functions-in-php-using-utf-8-strings) has a very clever answer to work around this. It's not 100% pure-bred, but probably workable in most cases.

If the characters you are using are also available in `iso-8859-1`, you could also try a simple `utf8_decode()`. But that solution is not complete and not perfect, as it will fail on characters outside the map.

Comment: (+1) Great comment. Didn't realise there was another work around :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [the unicode normalize functions](http://php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php) to normalize the filepath?

```
filePath = unicodedata.normalize('NFD', filePath);
```

Comment: He doesn't want to change the folder names. It's great to know about the normalizer though, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be a **[bug](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=25004&edit=1)** which i am not sure whether it has been solved or not. You can use the regular expression to **[clean file/folder names](http://protech.ws4.org/php/clean-file-name-php-regular-expression)** though. Or as pointed out by TheGrandWazoo you can use the **[normalizer](http://php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php)** class.