# File name with special chars

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I'm using SwiftMailer and trying to add an attachment with special chars and spaces in it's filename. How can I add such a file, f.e. "Informationen für alle Mitglieder.pdf"?

I use this command:

```
$message->attach("resources/assets/docs/Informationen für alle Mitglieder.pdf");
```

...but I'm getting always an file not found error. When I replace all special chars, it works fine?

Is there any "decoding function" to make it work? For white spaces, I can replace them easily with "\x20" and it works. But what's about the other chars like "äöü"?

Comment: don't use filenames with whitespaces it was and will never be a good solution

Comment: White spaces are not the problem, I can replace them with \x20 - but what's about "äöü". We have 2015, it's terrible that this is still a problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
$message->attach("resources/assets/docs/Informationen_fuer_alle_Mitglieder.pdf");
```

Just rename your .pdf. And don't take special characters and white spaces in your urls in future.

Maybe this is useful for you:

```
$string = "resources/assets/docs/Informationen für alle Mitglieder.pdf"
$string  = str_replace(' ', '%20', $string); // %20 means white space
$string  = str_replace('ü', '&uuml', $string); // %uuml means ü
echo $string;
```

EDIT2:

http://www.webspace-finden.de/html-php-ae-oe-ue-und-szett-zeichencodes/

> Ä – & Auml;
>
> ä – & auml;
>
> Ö – & Ouml;
>
> ö – & ouml;
>
> Ü – & Uuml;
>
> ü – & uuml;
>
> **remove white space behind "&" otherwise I couldn't show this**

http://php.net/manual/de/function.urlencode.php

```
<?php
echo urlencode($string); >;
?>
```

EDIT3:

```
$string = "resources/assets/docs/Informationen%20f&uumlr%20alle%20Mitglieder.pdf"
```

Comment: Nope, I need the special chars.

Comment: remembered something I've added in my answer

Comment: Yeah, that is for urls. For internal filenames I've to add "\x20" to replace white spaces. I've updated my question, because I've still problems with "äüö".

Comment: Hey Maurize, I'm sorry to say that it isn't working. urlencode() works for HTTP urls, "&auml;" and the others are for HTML. I need to encode that path to work with fopen("resources/assets/docs/Informationen für alle Mitglieder.pdf","r");

Comment: then this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216852/php-file-handling-special-characters-in-folder-names

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525830/how-do-i-use-filesystem-functions-in-php-using-utf-8-strings btw im german.

Comment: Why are you trying to escape for html though? I don't think this problem is anything to do with html

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the attach method correctly as per [the documentation](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html#attaching-existing-files)?

```
$message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('resources/assets/docs/Informationen für alle Mitglieder.pdf'));
```

Also, there is nothing wrong with spaces or extended ascii in filenames.  There are not many operating systems which dont support it.