# PHP file_exists and special characters like Å Ø Æ on a Linux box

Tags: php, linux, special-characters, file-exists

file_exists("file_å.txt");

Returns **false** while file is there. Is there any what to make *file_exists* to see the files with this kind of names?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [special characters in "file_exists" problem (php)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685718/special-characters-in-file-exists-problem-php)

Comment: Also see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46990

Comment: Not duplicate. That topic was related to windows-based box. But thanks for the link!

Answer (score 3):

I've run in to this a couple of times when for example reading filenames from an Excel and looking up a given path on disk. The problem may be that "ä" is either it's specific unicode char (\u00e4) or its "combined diaresis" form (a\u0308) ie an "a" with two dots.

Best solution since php 5.3 is to use the Normalizer library.
You may need `sudo apt-get install php5-intl` to get the class into your PHP. After that just

```
$normalizer = new \Normalizer();
$normalizer->normalize($val, \Normalizer::FORM_D)
```

Theres a few different forms for the second argument so you'll have to look up which one you need

Answer (score 2):

try

`file_exists(mb_convert_encoding("file_å.txt", "UTF-8"));`

assuming the text is not utf-8

Answer (score 2):

Check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2685818/190791

The solution for me was to convert to windows file format:

```
$winfilename= iconv('utf-8', 'cp1252', $utffilename);
```

Comment: This worked for me on file names which had a – symbol in them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check which encoding your php script is in. Probably it's different from the file systems. (E.g. latin1 vs. utf-8)

Comment: Yeah, the file is UTF-8. Not sure how to check what encoding is my hoister's filesystem. Will keep you updated. And thanks for the tip.

Comment: Are you sure that your php file is in UTF8? (not the file_å.txt file)

Comment: iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', 'file_å.txt') provides proper file naming in the browser, but still, *file_eixsts* cannot check if it exists.

Comment: Strange - Maybe try to run `scandir` on the folder which contains your file and see how it comes back to you?