# Special characters in file name cannot be found

Tags: php, file, encoding, utf-8

I have a list of files that I want to check if they exist with PHP
Here is a screenshot of the list (using Options +Indexes)

[image]

In PHP, I tried

- $name = iconv("utf-8", "utf-8//TRANSLIT", $name);
- file_exists(mb_convert_encoding($name, "UTF-8"));
- $name = iconv('utf-8', 'cp1252', $name);
- $name = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', $name);

None of them works...

By the way, it is a Linux server

EDIT :

I think I found a way to get to the solution. I need to transform the characters like "Sévère" into something like this "Se%CC%81ve%CC%80re%20". How can I do this conversion ?

Comment: That image is huge, can you replace it with a smaller one?

Comment: It depends on how your filesystem encodes the names, which depends on your system. What system are we talking about?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685718/special-characters-in-file-exists-problem-php

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525830/how-do-i-use-filesystem-functions-in-php-using-utf-8-strings - the .pdf filenames appear to be mangled when they have been stored on the windows file system.

Comment: @ValehHajiyev : I tried that answer, it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You just need to URL encode the utf-8.