# PHP file_exists with accent returns false

Tags: php, function, encoding, utf-8, non-ascii-characters

I have two folders, `Folder` and `Folderé`. The second one could not be catch by PHP.

Here is my test:

```
<?php
        $dir = 'D:\wamp\www\test\data\Folder';
        var_dump(file_exists($dir)); // true

        $dir = 'D:\wamp\www\test\data\Folderé';
        var_dump(file_exists($dir)); // false
?>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2685818/1438393) answer should help.

Comment: Yes on Windows, look at the path. :) Gonna see your link!
Still false...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This works like charm

```
<?php
$dir = 'D:\wamp\www\test\data\Folderé';
var_dump(file_exists((utf8_decode($dir))));
```

Comment: Not really... Still false. Thx

Comment: @sylouuu Indeed this works on PHP5.4. Try using `dirname(__FILE__) . '/test/data/Folderé'` instead

Comment: It's OK now, I tried the wrong file. Answer for my case: utf8_decode(urldecode($dir)). Thanks