# php unlink() non-ascii characters = file not found

Tags: php, unlink

To be brief;

php unlink is working with files if their name is asci. However unlink produce file not found error if i try to delete a file with a name including ç ö etc.

Is there any way that i can fix this? Or is it a problem caused by the relation between PHP & Operating System.

Comment: Could you post the code you are attempting?

Comment: Looks like an encoding issue, i.e. you pass the file name in ISO-8559-1, but the name is in UTF-8 in the operating system.

Comment: If the server is debian-like provide us a `locale` output from the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitive an encoding problem.

Try this (if './çö' isn't UTF-8, dynamicly loaded for example):

```
unlink(mb_convert_encoding('./çö', 'UTF-8'))
```

Maybe you are using Windows? From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2685818/2441442):

```
unlink(iconv('utf-8', 'cp1252', './çö'));
```

Anyway: You should avoid those filenames. If it comes from user: NEVER TRUST USER INPUT!

Comment: so i should read and write file names according to the os. .I should convert bin data to encoded strings with using code page conversions ?

Comment: @user2102266 Never has seen UTF-8 Symbols in Filenames. You should avoid it. Not understand what you mean with the second part.

Comment: yup both are working. `unlink(mb_convert_encoding('./çö', 'UTF-8'))` for lamp. `unlink(iconv('utf-8', 'cp1252', './çö'));` for wamp. thanks