# Unlink function error

Tags: php

I am currently facing a problem with character encoding.

In Url I got the name of image like "Meppen_Hafenstraße_test.jpg". In my server this image is also saved as "Meppen_Hafenstraße_test.jpg". so when i call `Unlink()` in my controller to remove the image from server it gives me an error.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: unlink(immobilien-boeker.de/assets/images/gallery/Meppen_Hafenstra%C3%9Fe_test.jpg) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory
>
> Filename: controllers/Boeker.php

so "ß" actually converted to "%C3%9F" .
I have no idea how to stop this encoding ? Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php unlink() non-ascii characters = file not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537833/php-unlink-non-ascii-characters-file-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

the string is URL encoded. You need to decode it, to get the ehmmm decoded version :)

\n";

$decoded = urldecode($test);
echo "Encoded" .$decoded."
\n";
?>

See http://php.net/urldecode and http://php.net/urlencode

Hope I could help.

Comment: Thank you So much. You just saved my life :D