# Unicoded filename cannot be saved in window filesystem using PHP

Tags: php

Here is my code

```
copy($_FILES['btnFile']['tmp_name'],"images/সাদাকালো-ছবি.jpg");
```

In OS windows i also tried with `utf8_encode()`, env() but not working only showing as follows:

à¦¸à¦¾à¦¦à¦¾à¦•à¦¾à¦²à§‹-à¦›à¦¬à¦¿.jpg

Comment: You will run into all sorts of OS specific issues when moving from OS to OS or version to version. Even regional settings or swapping partition types. If you still need to do this, add OS type, version, file system type and version and the PHP version to your post. It is likely you will need to submit a feature request to bugs.php.net.

Comment: [Please note that utf8_encode only converts a string encoded in ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php#Hcom104906)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research, I got some bad news for you:

> ALL php file system functions (dir, is_dir, is_file, file, filemtime,
>   filesize, file_exists etc) only accept and return file names in
>   ISO-8859-1, irrespective of the default_charset set in the program or
>   ini files.

However, you can scan a dir and use it's results. But `glob()` will fail if the ISO representative is ambiguous. Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525830/how-do-i-use-filesystem-functions-in-php-using-utf-8-strings).

Comment: latin1 assumption is only true for several codepages, before PHP 7.1 it's ANSI codepage that is used internally. Upgrading to 7.1 will let you use UTF-8. Thanks.