# Why does PHP built-in web server not serve file called é.txt (on Windows)

Tags: php, utf-8, http-status-code-404, command-line-interface, url-encoding

I'm on Windows 7

If I have a directory containing my file é.txt and I start the built-in web server in that directory

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

then, using my web browser, I request the URL

```
http://localhost:8000/é.txt
```

the web server responds

```
Not Found

The requested resource /%C3%A9.txt was not found on this server.
```

Comment: If you go `http://localhost:8000/` does it lists the directory structure (with the file in it)?

Comment: No, that's a 404 as well - but that is normal I think

Comment: I made a test: `php -S localhost:8000 é.txt` try it

Answer (score 0):

PHP's Windows filesystem support is broken - it does not properly translate to the native encoding.

See [How do I use filesystem functions in PHP, using UTF-8 strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525830/how-do-i-use-filesystem-functions-in-php-using-utf-8-strings)