# PHP built-in server serving only .php files

Tags: php

I created a dir named "test", and inside this dir, i created 3 files: 1.jpg, 2.html and 3.php. If i run `php -S localhost:80` and try to visit localhost/3.php, it works. But if i visit 1.jpg or 1.html, or any file that is not a php, it gives me a 404 not found error. I'm using PHP 7.1 NTS on Windows 10. I tried with PHP TS and PHP 7.2 but the error persists.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "mixing up the file extensions"?

Comment: I'm 100% sure i'm not doing this.

Comment: if its 404 thrown, make sure the image and html file are actually there

Comment: Believe me, dudes, the files are in there and i'm not visiting 1.php instead of 1.jpg.

Comment: Like i said, 3.php and any other php file is ok. So i assume i'm executing the command in the right directory. I'm going to post some prints.

Comment: I updated the question with the print.

Comment: @André The issue may be caused by the accented e in your file path, please test in a different location. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33150112/why-does-php-built-in-web-server-not-serve-file-called-%C3%A9-txt-on-windows

Comment: @mulquin, you are an angel. I'm changing my windows username right now. Do you want to write an answer so i can accept it as the best answer?

Comment: @André Sure, thanks for taking the time :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue may be caused by the accented e in your file path, please test in a different location. [Why does PHP built-in web server not serve file called é.txt (on Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33150112/why-does-php-built-in-web-server-not-serve-file-called-%C3%A9-txt-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem: my php page would display fine but no other page, including images on the php page would be served. The problem was asking the php development  server to serve a specific page:

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 myPage.php
```

Rather than:

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8000
```

In the later I have to include `myPage.php` in the url, but images and other files now display.