# PHP Transliteration and renaming files

Tags: php, file, cross-platform, renaming, transliteration

This is my problem. Files is not renaming. What I do wrong? What I do not see? This script is must to work in Windows and Unix. Script file in UNIX UTF-8 w/o BOM. Tryed Windows 1251, ANSI and still don't working.

```php
 <?php
 function Transliteration($FileName){ 
 $CharReplace = array (
'А'=>'A', 'Б'=>'B', 'В'=>'V',
'Г'=>'G', 'Д'=>'D', 'Е'=>'E',
'Ё'=>'E', 'Ж'=>'ZH', 'З'=>'Z',
'И'=>'I', 'Й'=>'J', 'К'=>'K',
'Л'=>'L', 'М'=>'M', 'Н'=>'N',
'О'=>'O', 'П'=>'P', 'Р'=>'R',
'С'=>'S', 'Т'=>'T', 'У'=>'U',
'Ф'=>'F', 'Х'=>'H', 'Ц'=>'TS',
'Ч'=>'CH', 'Ш'=>'SH', 'Щ'=>'SHH',
'Ъ'=>'', 'Ы'=>'I', 'Ь'=>'',
'Э'=>'E', 'Ю'=>'YU', 'Я'=>'YA',
'а'=>'a', 'б'=>'b', 'в'=>'v',
'г'=>'g', 'д'=>'d', 'е'=>'e',
'ё'=>'yo', 'ж'=>'zh', 'з'=>'z',
'и'=>'i', 'й'=>'j', 'к'=>'k',
'л'=>'l', 'м'=>'m', 'н'=>'n',
'о'=>'o', 'п'=>'p', 'р'=>'r',
'с'=>'s', 'т'=>'t', 'у'=>'u',
'ф'=>'f', 'х'=>'h', 'ц'=>'ts',
'ч'=>'ch',  'ш'=>'sh', 'щ'=>'shh',
'ъ'=>'', 'ы'=>'i', 'ь'=>'',
'э'=>'e', 'ю'=>'yu', 'я'=>'ya',
"№"=>"N", " "=>"_", "–"=>"_",
"-"=>"_", " - "=>"_", ","=>"");
$FileNameTranslited = str_replace(array_keys($CharReplace), $CharReplace, $FileName);
return $FileNameTranslited;}

function Renaming(){
$WorkDir = opendir("ToRename") or die("Не могу открыть папку");
while ($CurrentFile = readdir($WorkDir)){
    if ($CurrentFile != "." && $CurrentFile != ".."){
        $TranslitedFile = Transliteration($CurrentFile);
        if (rename($CurrentFile, $TranslitedFile))
            {echo "File Renamed";}
            else{echo "Some shit happen!";}
        echo $CurrentFile." -> ".$TranslitedFile."<br>";}}}

 Renaming();
 ?>
```

Thanks a lot StathisG! This is a right key for solution. But it still not working. Look here:

```
 function Renaming(){
 $directory = 'ToRename/';
 $WorkDir = opendir($directory) or die("Не могу открыть папку");
 while ($CurrentFile = readdir($WorkDir)){
   if ($CurrentFile != "." && $CurrentFile != ".."){
    $WhichCodingWeWant = 'UTF-8';
    $FileNameCoding = mb_detect_encoding($CurrentFile);
    echo $FileNameCoding."<br/>";
    $utf8_filename = mb_convert_encoding($CurrentFile, $WhichCodingWeWant, $FileNameCoding);
    $TranslitedFile = Transliteration($utf8_filename);
    mb_convert_encoding($TranslitedFile, $FileNameCoding, $WhichCodingWeWant);
    echo mb_detect_encoding($TranslitedFile)."<br/>";
    if (rename($directory . $CurrentFile, $directory . $TranslitedFile)) {
       echo "File Renamed<br/>";
       } else {
         echo "Some shit happen!<br/>";
          }
        echo $utf8_filename." -> ".$TranslitedFile."<br>";
       }
    }
 }
   Renaming();
```

As you can see I add a new Vars "$WhichCodingWeWant" and "$FileNameCoding".
Incoming file name: "Новый текстовый документ.txt" out "ГЌГ®ГўГ»Г©_ГІГҐГЄГ±ГІГ®ГўГ»Г©_Г¤Г®ГЄГіГ¬ГҐГ­ГІ.txt" mus be "Novij_textovij_document.txt"
My brain is exploded...

---

Okay...step 3. Incoming data like before: Новый текстовый документ.txt

```
 function Renaming(){
 $directory = 'ToRename/';
 $WorkDir = opendir($directory) or die("Не могу открыть папку");
 while ($CurrentFile = readdir($WorkDir)){
    if ($CurrentFile != "." && $CurrentFile != ".."){
        echo "What name is come: ".$CurrentFile."<br/>";
        $WhichCodingWeWant = 'UTF-8';
        $FileNameCoding = mb_detect_encoding($CurrentFile);
        echo "File name encoding: ".$FileNameCoding."<br/>";

        $utf8_filename = mb_convert_encoding($CurrentFile, $WhichCodingWeWant, $FileNameCoding);
        echo "File name behind transliting: ".$utf8_filename."<br/>";
        $TranslitedFile = Transliteration($utf8_filename);
        echo "File name translited to: ".$TranslitedFile."<br/>";

        mb_convert_encoding($TranslitedFile, $FileNameCoding, $WhichCodingWeWant);
        echo "File name encoding converted to: ".mb_detect_encoding($TranslitedFile)."<br/>";

        if (rename($directory . $CurrentFile, $directory . $TranslitedFile)) {
            echo "File Renamed<br/>";
        } else {
            echo "Some shit happen!<br/>";
        }
        echo $utf8_filename." -> ".$TranslitedFile."<br>";
    }
 }
 }
 Renaming();

 Result is: 
 What name is come: Новый текстовый документ.txt
 File name encoding: UTF-8
 File name behind transliting: ????? ????????? ????????.txt
 File name translited to: ?????_?????????_????????.txt
 File name encoding converted to: ASCII
```

Warning: : No error in E:\WEB\XAMPP\htdocs\my\Site\test\test6.php on line 32
Some shit happen!
????? ????????? ????????.txt -> ?????*?????????*????????.txt
And file is not renamed in folder.

Why ASCII if I want and making UTF-8? I understand that a I nothing to understand! Any way Thank You StathisG for trying to help me! I'll try this script tomorrow in Linux system. And tell you about results. If you will have a some ideas about this all, I will glad to see it :)

Comment: Maybe try using one of the [multibyte string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php).

Comment: Thanks, but can you tell me, which one of it I must to use? I never use it before.

Comment: I initially thought there was an issue with the replacement of the characters, but it turns out that there is another issue. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code produces the following warning:

> Warning: rename(test.txt, test.txt): The system cannot find the file
>   specified.

The `$CurrentFile` variable holds only the filename and not the complete path of the file. Try the following:

```
function Renaming(){
    $directory = 'ToRename/';
    $WorkDir = opendir($directory) or die("Не могу открыть папку");
    while ($CurrentFile = readdir($WorkDir)){
        if ($CurrentFile != "." && $CurrentFile != ".."){
            $utf8_filename = mb_convert_encoding($CurrentFile, 'UTF-8', 'GREEK');
            $TranslitedFile = Transliteration($utf8_filename);
            if (rename($directory . $CurrentFile, $directory . $TranslitedFile)) {
                echo "File Renamed";
            } else {
                echo "Some shit happen!";
            }
            echo $utf8_filename." -> ".$TranslitedFile."<br>";
        }
    }
}
Renaming();
```

I tested your `Transliteration` variable separately, and it seems to working fine (see test below), so ignore my original comment about the multibyte string functions.

`echo Transliteration('Не могу открыть папку'); // produces 'Ne_mogu_otkrit_papku'`

**EDIT:**

I edited the code above, adding the following line:

`$utf8_filename = mb_convert_encoding($CurrentFile, 'UTF-8', 'GREEK');`

Then, I used the `$utf8_filename` as the variable passed to your `Transliteration` function:

`$TranslitedFile = Transliteration($utf8_filename);`

As you may noticed, I used 'GREEK' as the filename's encoding, since that's the only language I know other than English, so I used Greek filenames to test your code.

I created a file called "τεστ.txt", and added the following values to the `$CharReplace` array: `'τ'=>'t', 'ε'=>'e', 'σ'=>'s'`

When I run the code, I got the following message, and the file was renamed successfully to "test.txt".

```
File Renamed τεστ.txt -> test.txt
```

Based on the PHP manual, the supported encodings for [`mb_convert_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) are [these](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php).

So, try the above code, replacing the encoding value with the encoding which corresponds to the characters you use and check if that solves your problem.

Comment: Yep I tryed this before. But this is not working. For example: In "ToRename" folder we have a file "Новый текстовый документ.txt" after this script we must to have a "Novij_textovij_document.txt". But we don't have it! After script only "Новый_текстовый_документ.txt" Only spaces was changed.

Comment: Please don't think about me like about your nightmare :) I edited my qestion.

Comment: @Baaakaaa Lol, that's ok. :) Unfortunately, I found a lot of questions regarding Cyrillic characters (which I assume is what you need), which have no solution at least for systems running windows. For example have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118990/unicode-issue-with-php), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008341/list-directories-containing-unicode-characters-on-windows), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977635/how-to-open-file-in-php-that-has-unicode-characters-in-its-name).

Comment: Also, the locale of the machine might have something to do as well. For example, I can write in Greek, so maybe that's why the example with the Greek filenames worked. By the way, what do you get if you `echo $CurrentFile;` before trying any change of encoding?

Comment: Hi StathisG! Look at upades in post (step 3) And thanks for links. Windows is like everytime...nothing good. Which OS you are use? Can you make a file with name like "Новый текстовый документ.txt" for tests?

Comment: @Baaakaaa I made the tests on Windows 7. I tested similar filenames, and in every test, the value of `$CurrentFile` consists of question marks. Based on your edit, the initial value of `$CurrentFile` that you get is correct, so my initial solution could work. Please try again the code of my answer, removing the `$utf8_filename = mb_convert_encoding...` line, and changing the next to `$TranslitedFile = Transliteration($CurrentFile);`. Also, echo the variables in every step to identify where the problem is (as you did in your last edit), and configure PHP to show all errors & warnings.

Comment: Hi StathisG! Sorry for long time without answers. I test this script in Debian, and this is working perfectly! But still do not working on Windows. Time is my enemy. Later I'll try your changes about windows script (last comment).