# cannot set right charset when uploading files

Tags: apache2, php, postgresql, upload

Please be patient and check this problem.

I wrote some simple PHP code for uploading images.

Here is the code (snippets)

```
 <?php

 header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

//set encoding for prepared statements
$dbh->exec("SET NAMES UTF8");
$dbh->query('SET NAMES UTF8');

//check if file is actually an image etc.

//send image to "upload" folder
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

//save to the database a string like "upload/myImage.jpg", so I can render it on the site later
$stu = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE multi SET m_place=:name WHERE m_id = :id");
$stu->bindParam(':name', $n, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$n= "upload/".$_FILES["file"]["name"];                                          
$stu->execute();
```

If the name of the image is in English, everything is fine. If is in Greek, it saved ok in the database , but not in the folder. In the database I see `χωρις τιτλο.jpg` (which is right) and in the folder `Ο‡Ο‰ΟΞ―Ο‚ Ο„Ξ―Ο„Ξ»ΞΏ.jpg` which is wrong.

I've tried everything and cannot fix this. To get the right titles in the folder.

The encoding of the database (postgreSQL 9.1) is UTF8, the Collation and the Character Type are `Greek_Greece.1235`. The collaction in table's column which I save the image's title is `pg_catalog."C"`.

I use DreamWeaver. The file that handles the uploads is a php file. Encoding is utf8, Unicode Normalization Form is C and the Include Unicode Signature (BOM) is unchecked.

The default language is Greek in Region and Language in the control panel. (Windows 7 Home Premium)

The encoding of the browser is utf8

I also use Apache 2.2.22. Is it Apache's fault? Or its the php file? Or the database?

I dont know what else to do...What am I missing? Please please please advice

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a StackOverflow issue and not related to ServerFault. However, you should take a look at this post:

For naming files in UTF-8:

[Can a PHP file name (or a dir in its full path) have UTF-8 characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708017/can-a-php-file-name-or-a-dir-in-its-full-path-have-utf-8-characters)

For writing files in UTF-8:

[How to write file in UTF-8 format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839402/how-to-write-file-in-utf-8-format)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out , I had not tried everything.

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204364/php-upload-utf-8-filename) I found the solution.

It has to do with PHP and how "PHP filesystem functions can only handle characters that are in system codepage"

So I used the `iconv` function.

I changed the code like so

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"upload/" . iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1253',$_FILES["file"]["name"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

For the application using japanese, the code page is cp932
This can be comfirm by using `chcp` command in commandline.

[image]

**Sample Code**

```
$fullPath = $uploadFolderPath."\\".iconv("utf-8", "cp932", $fileName);
move_uploaded_file($this->request->data["file_name"]['tmp_name'], $fullPath);
```